# What's the best NOSQL database for Python web applications?

Tags: python, nosql

Using Python to develop a web application which will be scaled later. I hear the scalability of the traditional relational database is not good. The replacement is the NOSQL database such as HBase or Google BigTable. I have two questions:
1. Which NOSQL database has the good performance and is quite stable today? And it should be easier to use for Python developers.
2. If I use NOSQL, can I still need to use traditional SQL database such as MYSQL to manage some data, too?

Comment: You should go with whatever storage technology fits your problem and requirements best and not just follow the hype of the week. Relational database systems can actually be scaled very well, and are proven technology.

Comment: Various question on SO deal with comparisons of various "noSQL" databases. So research a bit yourself and see what fits best to your requirements. Unless you don't tell us about your requirements there is little what we can recommend...as said: research first yourself. The Python bindings aspect is completely a step after choosing the right DB.

Comment: Checkout this blog: https://techwizardd.medium.com/database-for-python-developers-8e8734cfcaab

MongoDB is the most popular no-sql database.